# Save Google Oauth Profile Image as Base64 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-authentication

I need to save that profile picture returned from the google OAuth as base 64.

```
function Google_signIn(googleUser) {
    const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
    console.log('JSON: ' + profile._json.image.url());
}
```

from this function, I can get the image URL, but I want to save the image in Base64.

This is a example [URL](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/86arOE_jc_FYR6_mPbeXrzWB4LwvgCRWPGXbbftgG4_zAjY05ajbmq3xiG0Xc_uYCoTccikGvLdo5WIlofH5pmySn1VRejqngh2pwDLquiLJYayCOJKUrZKFnOwmSxKzQqqOM1y5o42TPk6LYR1vbPjrEPx3dQIUEwS4IPRjzt3JdPZT32TkqCECm-PoQtsBAPnyN6g46PbiyD9fblgzuBcT2xuO1AaZgOkR53bom8ATCBkDgcYT_mnsxWuxLGp6cNFUR4lWBFKyYkYJWJY--KmIVCWDDoJ3SxwjimGjwRG-X2Qu3AP4wa6tRazHuBo3a8IOofm6f5arSRdpVy4AaXoacTPz8TSkcofA0YaIttHpek1Gi5v1yMSbi5mHV6Mfv4lyczXPp8c5iNR7IFPvgMz1BiCETTxNwSvDjb2JCN94_256Fzejrs-Dk-kMYeCCYQh2Zd_lt9xiEQDgZ5gufdpxxM9xDiP447vrOqKbBMcAS_6hu43EwRi97ILAhBpS3QLP-4WhKf4GHauWqML_EcBvhszB-6T1iGeCWvpAT9jZVDVgekalBvLZiZNoy5Ow9QlnHA=w1827-h711-no).

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript

Comment: Why? Why not just hotlink the image?

Comment: @niklhs nop, It's not what I wanted to do.
I want to save that image locally.

Comment: @Ouroborus
Because I have given option to user to login using google or just upload image to the app.

Comment: It's a profile image, right? They either uploaded one or they didn't. If they did upload one, link to that. If they didn't upload one, hotlink directly to the google profile image. There's no actual need to keep a local copy of the google profile image.